# Get array of all left most points of a shape using OpenCV functions

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I have provided with a sample image, I want all the left most white points of the image.
The simplest way of doing it will be traversing each row from left and when reach the colored point store the coordiantes in the array.

but I feel there should be some OpenCV library function for doing this, instead of doing it manually, which I couldn't find.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, openCV provides an option to extract contour of the object. The image needs to be first converted to grayscale and after that you can use the below openCV API
    cvFindContours(imgGrayScale, storage, &contours, 
    sizeof(CvContour)CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE,cvPoint(0,0));
to detect the contour of the above object.

Pl. refer to the below url where the sample program has been provided. 
http://opencv-srf.blogspot.in/2011/09/object-detection-tracking-using-contours.html. 
Once we have extracted the contour of the image, we can specify the area by giving the x,y co-ordinates read the white points for that region. Tried this approach for one of our project to extract specific colour

Answer (score 0):

We can get find the Left most points of the given polygon using openCv

1. Convert input image to grascale  using

   cvCvtColor(img,grayScaleImg,CV_BGR2GRAY);
2. Threshold the grayscale image for better results using

   cvThreshold(grayScaleImg,grayScaleImg,128,255,CV_THRESH_BINARY);
3. Find the contours using OpenCV APi

   cvFindContours(grayScaleImg, storage, &contours, sizeof(CvContour),
      CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, cvPoint(0,0));

   in the above statement:

   CvSeq* contours; // contains Contour pointers
      CvMemStorage *storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0); // Contour storage memory
4. iterate through the contours to get the positions

   for(int i = 0; i < contours->total; i++){
               CvPoint* v=(CvPoint*)cvGetSeqElem(contours, i);
       }
5. We can get the requered points by sorting by X pos or Y pos.